# How to get getTag() value using OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclick, tags, onclicklistener

If I use the OnClick method the system can read the tag from each textView, but if I change to textView.SetOnClickListener the system only read the textview with tag 0 only. when I tried to click other textview the system cannot read its own tag. Where did i went wronggg?? what should I do??

```
package com.example.brainapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridLayout gridLayout;
    TextView textView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        textView =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

      textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("Tag : ", v.getTag().toString());

            }
        });


    }
}
```

here is my xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#FF0B0B"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="0"
            android:text="Tag 0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#712EE8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="1"
            android:text="Tag 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:background="#0D23EA"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="2"
            android:text="Tag 2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:background="#54FD5B"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="3"
            android:text="Tag 3" />

    </GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Help me!!!

Comment: why do u use multiple textview with same ids?

Comment: Ohh so the id needs to be diff?? I just try to see what will happen if the ids is all the same huhu.

Comment: if we have diff ids ... so it means I need to write onClickListener for 4 times?? for each tag??..

Comment: yes, you can make one method if all textview perform the same operation, then just call the method in all 4 onClickListener

Comment: yes it has to different ids and onClickListener should be written 4 times. Better stick to Onclick() for less coding and achieving what you expect.

Comment: @Erwin : That will do, Thank you sirr !!

Comment: @mdb  Alright then I will stick to the Onclick(), im just curious on how onClickListener will solve this problem. Thank You too!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same onClickListener and retrieve the tag from multiple views:

```
  TextView a = findViewById(R.id.A);
  TextView b = findViewById(R.id.B);

  View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String string = (String)v.getTag();
                Log.d("debug", string);
            }
        };
  a.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
  b.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

So you don't need to write more than one onClickListener just to do the same thing.